# How to use libraries in imported module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create a telegram bot using pytelegrambotapi. I decided to write every functions in separate files like files bellow, but I don't know how to use a library in main file and use it in other files (modules) ?

main.py :

```
import telebot
def call_back(call):
    setadmins.callback(call)
```

setadmins.py (module) :

```
def callback(call):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    # rest of code is not related
```

The error that python interpreter returns is :
*NameError: name 'telebot' is not defined*

Im using python 3.6.9 (linux mint stock)

and in the end , sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: "I decided to write every functions in separate files like files" ...why? This isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: @Chris bot writing all functions in one file is not a good way, it can be hard to read and edit

Comment: I'm only seeing what you shared here, but it is _definitely_ more idiomatic to put related functions in the same file. One-file-per-function will look very strange to Python folks. Plus, now you've just shifted the problem: instead of a bunch of functions that are hard to read and edit now you have a bunch of _files_ that are hard to read and edit. Organize your code logically, not based on some arbitrary "each function gets its own file" rule. It's definitely possible to have readable Python code with more than one thing in each file. I'm not sure one-file-per-function can be readable.

Comment: @Chris i think i have told it in a bad way , i'm not trying to put only one function in a file , i want to separate by them performance. for example all setting functions in one file , all google search functions in one file and etc.

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the name `telebot.types` the module source `setadmins.py` must include

```
import telebot
```

(typically placed near the top of the module).

Similarly `main.py` will have to include

```
import setadmins
```

Comment: bot i don't have one module , there can be many others and i don't want to import telebot to every one of them , if there is no other way , I have to do this.

Comment: @rezamnk, you're the one who decide to break your code up this way. Python doesn't let you use things that aren't in scope, which in my opinion makes it pretty well-behaved.

Comment: Note that "imports" are cached by the python runtime.  When a second or third module invokes "import telebot" it is resolved immediately, not heavy at all.

Comment: @Chris so you're saying doing all things in one file is better ? idk why but i don't like this :(

Comment: No, I'm saying you should break your code apart _logically_. That doesn't necessarily mean everything goes in one file either. Maybe you'll end up with two or three files. Maybe one. Maybe twelve, in a nested directory structure. But I think most Python developers would find one file per function very awkward.